# Beginner Python script for calculating GC content in DNA sequence

Tags: python, function, rosalind

I'm trying to calculate the GC content (in %) of a DNA sequence for a Rosalind question. I have the following code, but it returns 0, or only the number of G's alone or C's alone (no percentage).

```
x = raw_input("Sequence?:").upper()
total = len(x)
c = x.count("C")
g = x.count("G")

gc_total = g+c

gc_content = gc_total/total

print gc_content
```

I also tried this, just to get a count of G's and C's, and not the percentage, but it just returns a count of the entire string:

```
x = raw_input("Sequence?:").upper()
def gc(n):
    count = 0
    for i in n:
        if i == "C" or "G":
            count = count + 1
        else:
            count = count
    return count
gc(x)
```

EDIT: I fixed the typo in the print statement in the first example of code. That wasn't the problem, I just pasted the wrong snippet of code (there were many attempts...)

Comment: The first one might be a typo, but you said 'cg_content' instead of 'gc_content'.  There is no need for the else statement in the second example.

Comment: I fixed it in an edit. That wasn't the root of the problem, I just pasted the wrong block of code from my many, many attempts trying different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't:

> print cg_content

read

> print gc_content?

As for the other snippet of code, your loop says

> if i == "C" or "G":

This is evaluating "G" to true every time and thus running the if statement as true.

Instead, it should read

> if i == "C" or i=="G":

Also, you don't need that else statement.

Hope this helps. Let us know how it goes.

Abdul Sattar

Comment: Yes that worked! My if statement was off. As fast as the typo in the print statement, that was a result of me scrolling through all the various iterations of the code above to paste an example to show you guys. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is that you are performming integer division, not floating point division.

Try

```
gc_content = gc_total / float(total)
```

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you! Is there ever really any reason to use integer division? Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to multiply the answer by 100 to convert it to a percentage.

Answer (score 0):

```
#This works for me.

import sys

filename=sys.argv[1]

fh=open(filename,'r')

file=fh.read()
x=file
c=0
a=0
g=0
t=0

for x in file:
    if "C" in x:
        c+=1    
    elif "G" in x:
        g+=1
    elif "A" in x:
        a+=1    
    elif "T" in x:
        t+=1

print "C=%d, G=%d, A=%d, T=%d" %(c,g,a,t)

gc_content=(g+c)*100/(a+t+g+c)

print "gc_content= %f" %(gc_content)
```

Comment: It's best practice on SO to accompany a source code block with a few words of explanation.

Comment: Did you consider the header of the sequences, no?

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
orignfile = sys.argv[1]
outfile = sys.argv[2]

sequence = ""
with open(orignfile, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('>'):
            seq_id = line.rstrip()[0:]
        else:
            sequence += line.rstrip()
GC_content = float((sequence.count('G') + sequence.count('C'))) / len(sequence) * 100
with open(outfile, 'a') as file_out:
    file_out.write("The GC content of '%s' is\t %.2f%%" % (seq_id, GC_content))
```

Comment: Please avoid code-only answers. Check the [tour] and read [answer]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too late but it is better using Bio

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
from Bio import SeqIO

filename=sys.argv[1]

fh= open(filename,'r')

parser = SeqIO.parse(fh, "fasta")

for record in parser:
    c=0
    a=0
    g=0
    t=0
    for x in str(record.seq):
        if "C" in x:
            c+=1    
        elif "G" in x:
            g+=1
        elif "A" in x:
            a+=1    
        elif "T" in x:
            t+=1
gc_content=(g+c)*100/(a+t+g+c)

print "%s\t%.2f" % (filename, gc_content)
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful

```
import random
dna=''.join(random.choice('ATGCN') for i in range(2048))
print(dna)
print("A count",round((dna.count("A")/2048)*100),"%")
print("T count",round((dna.count("T")/2048)*100),"%")
print("G count",round((dna.count("G")/2048)*100),"%")
print("C count",round((dna.count("C")/2048)*100),"%")
print("AT count",round((dna.count("AT")/2048)*100),"%")
print("GC count",round((dna.count("GC")/2048)*100),"%")
```